# EFCore 5 count child records of a child of a parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, parent-child, counting

I tried to find first, sorry if it's duplicate.

I have a "Posts" table, and a "Users" table.
Each Post is written by an User.
My models looks like:

```
[Table("Post")]
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public User Author { get; set; }
}

[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int PostCount { get; set; }
}
```

I can include the Authors by doing this:

```
return _context.Set<Post>()
    .Include(p => p.Author)
    .ToList();
```

But I don't know how to fill the "PostCount" property with the number of Posts of each Author.

Is it possible to make efficiently using EF? I'm almost giving up and writing it in plain SQL.

Comment: Without a setter on the property, you can't fill it in any way.

Comment: Does the User class not contain a collection navigation property for the posts? If you had that, then it would be quite trivial.

Comment: In addition to Hank's suggestion, is there a _need_ to add this computed value as a property? Can you compute the value as you need it?

Comment: @gunr2171 I always will need the post counter of each user of each post.

Comment: @HankMcCord I just added the setter, and I can add the collection to the User as long it doesn't change the tables structure. It's not trivial for me, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not a big fan of [NotMapped] properties because everytime im trying to use them or to find how to use them i just fail so my answer will be a little different.

So, first thing to do

```
    [Table("Post")]
    public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int PostCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Changes in your models:

1. `virtual` keyword for User and Posts. They are used for lazy-loading support.
2. `public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }`.
3. (I'd remove NotMapped prop but it is up to you)

Now about usage:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
{
    var postWithAuthor = db.Posts
        .Include(p => p.Author)//.ThenInclude(a => a.Posts)
        .Select(p => new { Post = p, PostsCount = p.Author.Posts.Count })
        .Where(x => x.Post.Content == "content1")
        .FirstOrDefault();

    return postWithAuthor;
}
```

That query will generate the following SQL query

```
Executed DbCommand (21ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT "p"."ID", "p"."AuthorID", "p"."Content", "u"."ID", "u"."Username", (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "Post" AS "p0"
          WHERE "u"."ID" = "p0"."AuthorID")
      FROM "Post" AS "p"
      INNER JOIN "User" AS "u" ON "p"."AuthorID" = "u"."ID"
      WHERE "p"."Content" = 'content1'
      LIMIT 1
```

The resulting object will look like that:
`{ Post = {EFCorePlayground.API.DAL.Post}, PostsCount = 4 }`. Author entity will also be loaded `AND important part here` - loaded Author will have only 1 loaded Post in its Posts collection. If you uncomment .ThenInclude part in my code - all 4 posts will be loaded from database which is not what you need.

I used the following Seed for that:

```
        static void Seed()
        {
            var authors = new List<User>
            {
                new User() { Username = "user 1" },
                new User() { Username = "user 2" },
            };

            var posts = new List<Post>
            {
                new Post(){ Author = authors[0], Content = "content1" },
                new Post(){ Author = authors[0], Content = "content" },
                new Post(){ Author = authors[0], Content = "content" },
                new Post(){ Author = authors[0], Content = "content" },
                new Post(){ Author = authors[1], Content = "content" },
                new Post(){ Author = authors[1], Content = "content" },
            };
            using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                db.users.AddRange(authors);
                db.Posts.AddRange(posts);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Last part:

[image: Debugger screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Posts` property to `User` entity so can get post count by author.

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {          
      Posts = new List<Post>(); //for prevent NullException   
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int PostCount  => Posts.Count();
}
```

Comment: I probably did something wrong, but after adding virtual ICollection and => Posts.Count() returned me 1 instead of 4 on my dataset. Dataset is in one of the answers in this post. I think it will not work until .ThenInclude is called for User to load all the posts from database, which is not efficient